# Nginx doesn't compress jscript

Tags: apache, nginx, centos

I am migrating from the apache web server and have problems with nginx jscript compression (**css compression works fine**). This is my config file:

```
#user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

#pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #tcp_nodelay        on;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_min_length 10;
    #gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 7;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml application/xhtml+xml application/xml;
    #gzip_min_length  1100;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

When I check different file compression using online check tools, jscript files are not compressed at all. css and text files are OK.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

**UPDATE: Having spent 5 hours in debugging this simple thing I've found the problem:**

after changing the nginx configuration files reloading nginx (/etc/init.d/nginx reload) is not enough - **the nginx services on Plesk panel should be restarted** (off/on). Otherwise, the changes will not be applied.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
application/javascript
```

to gzip_types

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work. css files and js.php are OK, but simple js files are not compressed.